# How do I center the image with the single line of text for functions.php?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

Currently, with the way I wrote the code, the image lines up with the text that is too high up. I would like it centered with the text. Here is the way it looks now. Everything else is centered right and how I like it except for the image. Is there a way to give it a negative margin or image padding to lower the image more or something else? New to coding so not sure how to do it.

[example image of how it currently looks with code written below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFPtx.png)

[example image of how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tM3a.png)

This is the current code I have that goes with the example image.

```
function add_text_in_between(){
    echo '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <img src="https://e-z-hook.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Prop-65-Warning-Label-transparent-background.png", width="40" height="40"/>'; 
    echo '<b> &nbsp; &nbsp; WARNING: </b> Cancer and Reproductive Harm - <a href="https://www.P65Warnings.ca.gov"> www.P65Warnings.ca.gov</a>, see E-Z-Hooks website for more information on <a href="https://www.e-z-hook.com/compliance/"> California Proposition 65</a> <p style="margin-top: 20px"> </p>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_tabs', 'add_text_in_between', 20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code instead of the two `echo` statements in your function.

```php
echo '<div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
    <img src="https://e-z-hook.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Prop-65-Warning-Label-transparent-background.png"
         style="height: 40px; width: 40px; margin-right: 15px;"/>
    <p>
        <b> WARNING: </b>Cancer and Reproductive Harm - <a href="https://www.P65Warnings.ca.gov">www.P65Warnings.ca.gov</a>, see E-Z-Hooks website for more information on<a href="https://www.e-z-hook.com/compliance/"> California Proposition 65</a>
    </p>
</div>';
```

The code above uses flex box to align the items.
To change the width of the space between the image and the text update the following in the code `margin-right: <desired width>px;`.